# A c program from GATE paper

Tags: c, pointers

Hey all yesterday i have given my GATE exam and in this exam there was a question:

**What does the following fragment of C-program print?**

```
char c [] = "GATE2011";
char *p =c;
printf ( "%s", p+p [3] − p [1]) ;
```

options:

```
(A) GATE2011
(B) E2011
(C) 2011
(D) 011
```

Answer is '`C`'. when i tried the code on my computer But how??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's pointer arithmetic:

```
char c [] = "GATE2011";
// indices:  01234567
char *p =c;
```

`p[1]` is `A` character code, `p[3]` is `E` character code, their difference (`E` code minus `A` code) is 4, that difference is then added to `p` pointer and you've got the address of `2011` substring passed into `printf()`.

Comment: Unpredictable. Thanks sharptooth.

Answer (score 0):

Here p[3] = E p[1]= A ascii of A --> 65 and E-->69
69-65 = 4 p+4 will point to 4th index of string GATE2011 01234567

SO...2011`char[c]="GATE2011"`