# how does following program work pointer manipulation

Tags: c, pointers, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A c program from GATE paper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989416/a-c-program-from-gate-paper)

Here is a program which is working

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main ()
{
char c[]="GATE2011";
char *p=c;
printf("%s",p+p[3]-p[1]);
}
```

The output is

```
2011
```

Now comes the problem I am not able to understand the operation p+p[3]-p[1]
what is that pointing to?

My understanding is when I declare some thing like

```
char c[]="GATE2011"
```

Then c is a pointer pointing to a string constant and the string begins with G.
In next line `*p=c;`
the pointer p is pointing to same address which c is pointing.
So how does the above arithmetic work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty horrid code.  `(p+p[3]-p[1])` is simply adding and subtracting offsets to `p`.  `p[3]` is `(char)'E'`, which is 69 in ASCII.  `p[1]` is `(char)'A'`, which is 65 in ASCII.  So the code is equivalent to:

```
(p+69-65)
```

which is:

```
(p+4)
```

So it's simply offseting the pointer by 4 elements, before passing it to `printf`.

Technically, this is *undefined behaviour*.  The first part of that expression (`p+69`) offsets the pointer beyond the end of the array, which is not allowed by the C standard.

Answer (score 8):

`p[3]` is 'E', `p[1]` is 'A'. The difference between the ASCII codes A and E is 4, so `p+p[3]-p[1]` is equivalent to `p+4`, which in turn is equivalent to `&p[4]`, and so points to the '2' character in the char array.

Anyone found writing this sort of thing in production code would be shot, though.

Answer (score 3):

That is

```
pointer + char - char
```

which has a pointer value

It's basic pointer arithmetic ...

You can add some parenthesis *(in a different order than the language specifies but resulting in the same value)* to make it easier to understand

```
pointer + (char - char)
```

or

```
p + ('E' - 'A')
```

or

```
p + 4
```

which is

```
&p[4]
```

or the string `"2011"`.

Comment: The parenthesising should be the other way round, as addition and subtraction are left-associative...

Comment: @pmg thanks man I am trying to improve upon my C I read and re read Kernighnan Ritchie but I was not able to do the above problem is it possible to refer any book or link where I can understand more such pointer manipulations?

Comment: @Oli: yes, you're right ... but `(p + 'E')` is UB :)

Comment: @pmg: No it isn't!  It's horrible, but it's not UB.

Comment: @Oli: imagine the original `c` array (9 bytes long) is at address `0xFFFFFFF0`: `p + 'E'` crosses the `0x100000000` boundary.

Comment: @pmg: Oh, sorry, yes you're right.  For a minute, I had convinced myself that `'E'` was `5`!  Yes, it is UB.

Comment: @Registered: write code, understand your mistakes, ask others (SO is great). I don't really know any good sites, except for [the c-faq](http://c-faq.com/), especially section 6 for pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Simple math.

`p[3]` = 'E', `p[1]` = 'A'

The whole thing is `p+'E'-'A'` which is 'p+4', which points to the '2'.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main ()
{
char c[]="GATE2011";   
char *p=c;  // here you allocated address of character array c into pointer p

printf("%s",p+p[3]-p[1]); 
/*  p refers to the memory location of c[0],if you add any thing in p
    i.e p+1 it becomes next block of memory,in this case p+p[3]-p[1]
    takes 4 bytes forward and gives 2011 as output    */
}
```